# Powershell Nested foreach loop with multiple arrays

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have two files "name.txt" and "path.txt, contents for each file are below:

name.txt:

```
John
Mike
Paul
```

path.txt:

```
C:\directory\john.config
C:\directory\mike.config
C:\directory\paul.config
```

I want to print n'th line from each file together

Code:

```
$name = Get-Content "C:\path\name.txt"
$path = Get-Content "C:\path\path.txt"
foreach($var1 in $name){
foreach($var2 in $name){
Write-Host "$name - $path
}
}
```

Desired output:

```
John - C:\directory\john.config
Mike - C:\directory\mike.config
Paul - C:\directory\paul.config
```

My Output:

```
John - C:\directory\john.config C:\directory\mike.config 
C:\directory\paul.config
Mike - C:\directory\john.config C:\directory\mike.config 
C:\directory\paul.config
Paul - C:\directory\john.config C:\directory\mike.config 
C:\directory\paul.config
```

I want to get the desired output, can anyone please help me how I can get the desired output?

Comment: What have you written so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We are here to help you with problems in code that you are writing.

Comment: Let me edit the question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work but without knowing a bit more about what you are trying to achieve it's difficult to tell whether it is a sensible solution or not.

```
$names = ( Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\name.txt' )
$paths = ( Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\path.txt' )
for($i = 0; $i -lt $names.Length; $i++) {
    Write-Host ( '{0} - {1}' -f $names[$i], $paths[$i] )
}
```

Comment: If there is a need only for lines consists both parts it can be considered `$i -lt [math]::min($names.Length, $paths.Length)` as loop condition.